# Перезапуск функции python

Tags: python, функции, requests

Есть проблема. Как мне перезапустить функцию function1_request?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import time

def function1_request(url):
    HEADERS = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.152 YaBrowser/21.2.3.100 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36'
    }
    ret_url = requests.get(url, HEADERS)
    ret_url1 = str(ret_url)
    voz_normal = ret_url1.find('200')
    voz_rate_limit = ret_url1.find('429')
    if voz_normal != -1:
        return ret_url
    elif voz_rate_limit == -1:
        print('fawwfa')
        time.sleep(600)
        #здесь нужно начать функцию заново
    else:
        print('Ошибка в распознавании')
        exit()
```

Comment: Вот так: `function1_request(url)` Только exit стоит убрать)

Comment: Зациклите ее вызов либо вызов кода внутри нее пока не получите удовлетворительный результат

Comment: А как конкретно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавил пример зацикливания, сделал рефакторинг

Алгоритм:

- Функция повторяет вызов и если результат успешный (200), то сразу выполняется выход из функции
- Если результат [429 Too Many Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429), то засыпаем на 10 минут и на следующей итерации повторим запрос
- Если в результате что-то другое, то выходим из функции, возвращая `None`

Пример:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import time

def function1_request(url):
    HEADERS = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.152 YaBrowser/21.2.3.100 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36'
    }
    while True:
        rs = requests.get(url, HEADERS)        
        if rs.status_code == 200:
            return rs
        elif rs.status_code == 429:
            print('fawwfa')
            time.sleep(600)
        else:
            print('Ошибка в распознавании')
            return


url = ...
rs = function1_request(url)
if not rs:
    exit()
    
print(rs)
```

Answer (score 0):

А можно вот так вот?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import time

def function1_request(url):
    HEADERS = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.152 YaBrowser/21.2.3.100 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36'
    }
    ret_url = requests.get(url, HEADERS)
    ret_url1 = str(ret_url)
    voz_normal = ret_url1.find('200')
    voz_rate_limit = ret_url1.find('429')
    if voz_normal != -1:
        #print('Работает')
        return ret_url
    elif voz_rate_limit != -1:
        print('Поймал временный бан из-за запросов')
        time.sleep(600)
        return function1_request(url)
    else:
        print('Ошибка в распознавании')
        print(ret_url)
        exit()
```

Comment: Можно, но в данном случае лучше так не делать, т.к. стек вызовов (максимальное количество вложенных вызовов) ограничено.

Comment: Ну и ret_url нужно из `function1_request` принимать и передавать дальше вниз по вызовам.

Comment: Хорошо, тогда переделаю, спасибо

Comment: Стоп, то есть при вызове функции return python заканчивает выполнение функции или он продолжит ее бесконечно выполнять,, так как while true?

Comment: При return выполнение возвращается на предыдущий уровень вызова (в вызвавший код, даже если это как бы та же самая функция), т.е. чтобы совсем выйти из функции должно выполниться столько return (или столько раз дойти до конца функци), сколько было вложенных вызовов. Ну или сработать принудительный `sys.exit()`. Почитайте про рекурсию.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо!